# Ajax triggering body's onLoad event

Tags: javascript, ajax, onload

My whole page is loading again whenever I make a ajax call to load a div.
I have noticed that 'body onload=init()' onload event is getting triggered on ajax response and all the initialization is happening again. I don't want that to happen.
Is there a way by which only div is loaded through ajax call.

```
<body onload="init()">
.....
.....
<div>...<a href="" onclick="saveView('more')"><b>More</b></a></div>
</body>
```

main.js

```
function saveView(arg){
    if(arg=="more"){
            ajaxGet(baseRef+"all.html", loadList);

    }else{
            ajaxGet(baseRef+"all-A.html", loadList);

    }
function init(){
.....
}

function ajaxGet(url, responseHandler)
{
    var page_request = false;

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest && !(window.ActiveXObject && window.location.protocol == "file:")) { 
                // use this only if available, and not using IE on a local filesystem
        page_request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
    else if (window.ActiveXObject) { // older versions of IE, or IE on a local filesystem
        try {
            page_request = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        } 
        catch (e){
            try{
                page_request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            catch (e){
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        alert("Your browser does not support XMLHTTP.");
        return false;
    }


    page_request.onreadystatechange=function() {
        if(page_request.readyState==4) {
                        // on local machines the status for success is 0. on web servers it is 200
            if(page_request.status==200 || page_request.status==0) {
                responseHandler(page_request);
            }
        }
    }

    page_request.open('GET', url, true);
    page_request.send(null);
}

function loadList(page_request){
    document.getElementById("list").innerHTML=page_request.responseText;
    Loaded = true;    
    try{
        if(pLoaded) 
            doFilterStateChange1();
        }catch(e)
        {
        }
    setTimeout("restoreScrollTop()", 1000);
}
```

Comment: Please provide more details, like the HTML and JS code you use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not ajax that is triggering onLoad event of body. 
If you see the anchor tag, I haven't assigned any value to href="" which was causing the page to be loaded again. Removing it solved the problem.

Comment: If href attribute is removed from anchor tag then hand cursor will not show when cursor is hovered over it. The solution is to keep href and assign the value # i.e. href="#"

Answer (score 0):

We'd need to see your code to help, but when pages do things like reloading etc, it usually means their is a script error.  Use firebug to check for errors, it might be hard to catch if it's refreshing quickly.

Comment: It should have been a comment.