# Why is body onload = javascript function executed continuously?

Tags: javascript, ajax, onload

Sorry for the really newbie question, just starting to learn AJAX.

I'd like to understand what exactly in the following causes the divMessage content to change continuously when "myName" text is changed.

1) It would seem that the Javascript function process is constantly "listening", is this normal Javscript behavior, or are there any triggers to call "process" repeatedly? 
2) Is it true that any function that we assign to "body onload" will be executed repeatedly? How often is this repeated execution?
3) What if we want a single execution of the function process, how to do this?

4) I'm confused because I'm thinking the body will only load once. But is it because after "body onload" the function "process" is called, and the function process in turn modifies the "body" by changing the divMessage, essentially letting it go thru "body onload" again, then "process" again, etc.. ?

Thanks a lot in advance for your help!

```
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="quickstart.js"></script>
</head>
<body onload='process()'>
  Server wants to know your name:
  <input type="text" id="myName" />
  <div id="divMessage" />
</body>
```

Here's quickstart.js processing parts

```
function process()
{
  // proceed only if the xmlHttp object isn't busy
  if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4 || xmlHttp.readyState == 0)
  {
    // retrieve the name typed by the user on the form
    name = encodeURIComponent(
    document.getElementById("myName").value);
    // execute the quickstart.php page from the server
    xmlHttp.open("GET", "quickstart.php?name=" + name, true);
    // define the method to handle server responses
    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = handleServerResponse;
    // make the server request
    xmlHttp.send(null);
  }
}

  // callback function executed when a message is received from the server
  function handleServerResponse()
  {
    // move forward only if the transaction has completed
    if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4)
    {
      // status of 200 indicates the transaction completed successfully
      if (xmlHttp.status == 200)
      {
        xmlResponse = xmlHttp.responseXML;
        xmlDocumentElement = xmlResponse.documentElement;
        helloMessage = xmlDocumentElement.firstChild.data;

        // display the data received from the server
        document.getElementById("divMessage").innerHTML =
                  '<i>' + helloMessage+ '</i>';
      }
    }
  }
```

and the quickstart.php

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/xml');
echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>';
echo '<response>';
$name = $_GET['name'];

// generate output depending on the user name received from client
$userNames = array('YODA', 'AUDRA', 'BOGDAN', 'CRISTIAN');
if (in_array(strtoupper($name), $userNames))
  echo 'Hello, master ' . htmlentities($name) . '!';
else if (trim($name) == '')
  echo 'Stranger, please tell me your name!';
else
  echo htmlentities($name) . ', I don't know you!';

echo '</response>';
?>
```

Comment: It (the document load event) should be executed exactly once, barring some browser quirks (old IE and iframes?). I do know if re-opening the document object (e.g. document.write) should re-trigger it, but DOM manipulation (even `innetHTML`) should generally not .. or perhaps I have been using jQuery for so long I forget how broken it is plain, IDK.

Comment: In any case, please tag with the browser(s) this is observed in.

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5418216/ajax-triggering-bodys-onload-event (perhaps). Or, is `process` being called from *anywhere* else (besides the onload)?

Comment: @pst tried Firefox 14.0.1 and IE 8. This behavior is not really a problem, just wanted to know the mechanism for the continuous AJAX calls. Nope, no other calls to process aside from onload.. Thanks!

Comment: I don't think the observed behavior is is what it appears to be .. instead of `innerHTML =`, use `innerHTML +=`; does it *really* append repeatedly (as in, the HTML grows and grows)?

Comment: Yep, changed to +=, but still same behavior, divMessage just changes (as expected) whenever I change type a new name. Btw, just changed the question to "executed continuously", probably "executed repeatedly" was misleading. So, would this be constant background "listening"?

Comment: Tried Firebug, shows successive calls every ~6-10ms.

Comment: Have a jsfiddle test by chance? I guess that cross-XHR is problematic  ..

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer by shutting down and trying to run this again. 
It turns out there was additional code that I commented out 
but was cached that calls "process" every 1 second from handleServerResponse():

```
// display the data received from the server
    document.getElementById("divMessage").innerHTML =
              '<i>' + helloMessage+ '</i>';
    setTimeout('process()', 1000);
```

Sorry about that. Lesson is to clear the browser cache before testing each code change :)
So I guess the advice to check if this function is called from any other place is correct.
Anyway, I read a great deal and learned a lot while trying to figure 
this out. Thanks a lot @pst!